# How to create a dict of dicts from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe `df`

```
id      price      date         zipcode
u734    8923944    2017-01-05   AERIU87
uh72    9084582    2017-07-28   BJDHEU3
u029    299433     2017-09-31   038ZJKE
```

I want to create a dictionary with the following structure

```
{'id': xxx, 'data': {'price': xxx, 'date': xxx, 'zipcode': xxx}}
```

What I have done so far

```
ids = df['id']
prices = df['price']
dates = df['date']
zips = df['zipcode']
d = {'id':idx, 'data':{'price':p, 'date':d, 'zipcode':z} for idx,p,d,z in zip(ids,prices,dates,zips)}
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but I get the error above.

What would be the correct way to do this, using either

- list comprehension

OR

- pandas .to_dict()

**bonus points:** what is the complexity of the algorithm, and is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: can it be multiple id rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the list comprehension.

```
v = df.pop('id')
data = [
   {'id' : i, 'data' : j} 
   for i, j in zip(v, df.to_dict(orient='records'))
]
```

Or a compact version,

```
data = [dict(id=i, data=j) for i, j in zip(df.pop('id'), df.to_dict(orient='r'))]
```

Note that, if you're popping `id` inside the expression, it *has* to be the first argument to `zip`.

```
print(data)
[{'data': {'date': '2017-09-31',
   'price': 299433,
   'zipcode': '038ZJKE'},
  'id': 'u029'},
 {'data': {'date': '2017-01-05',
   'price': 8923944,
   'zipcode': 'AERIU87'},
  'id': 'u734'},
 {'data': {'date': '2017-07-28',
   'price': 9084582,
   'zipcode': 'BJDHEU3'},
  'id': 'uh72'}]
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not `pop`ing inside `zip`?

Comment: @coldspeed it works but produces different results depending on the order of arguments. Wanted to hear your motive.

Comment: @AntonvBR oh, _that_'s how you guys meant it? Sorry, totally misunderstood.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko um, sorry. I misunderstood. yes, I popped it outside for readability.

Comment: @coldspeed No worries. I think it even makes sense in this case as it is easier (debatable) to read.

Comment: How do I get this to the desired structure `{'id': xxx, 'data': {'price': xxx, 'date': xxx, 'zipcode': xxx}}` ?

Comment: @killerT2333 if you are familiar with how dictionaries in python work, you should know that they are not ordered.